# How to set an attribute for row with minimum value for different keys

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have table(not good but need to to here) like this:

```
Sessions

    user_id | time  | registration time | diff | before_reg |is_registration_session
       1    | 00:10 |       00:30       | -20  |     True   |   Null
       1    | 00:20 |       00:30       | -10  |     True   |   Null
       1    | 00:27 |       00:30       | -3   |     True   |   Null
       1    | 00:31 |       00:30       |  1   |     False  |   Null
       2    | 00:14 |       00:20       | -6   |     True   |   Null
       2    | 00:26 |       00:20       |  6   |     False  |   Null
```

What I want to achieve: I want to find row with minimal(maximum negative) `reg_diff` for each `user_id` and set value in column `is_registration_session` to `True`. Only one way I did it is FOR LOOP in python with a lot of queries with "UPDATE/SET" And it takes too much time.

```
Sessions

    user_id | time  | registration time | diff | before_reg |is_registration_session
       1    | 00:10 |       00:30       | -20  |     True   |   False
       1    | 00:20 |       00:30       | -10  |     True   |   False
       1    | 00:27 |       00:30       | -3   |     True   |   True
       1    | 00:31 |       00:30       |  1   |     False  |   False
       2    | 00:14 |       00:20       | -6   |     True   |   True
       2    | 00:26 |       00:20       |  6   |     False  |   False
```

Comment: Why is user_id 1 having True at -3 and not -20?

Comment: Because it is the closest session to registration_time

Comment: Ok you  mean least negative, not maximum negative?

Comment: techanically maximum negative number is the closest number to zero, but you understand me correctly,yes

Comment: Does table `sessions` have a primary key?

Comment: @MikeOrganek It has index as serial primary key for all sessions

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to resolve this. For example:

```
select
  user_id, time, registration time, diff, before_reg,
  (diff < 0 and diff = max(diff) over (partition by user_id))
    as is_registration_session
from t
```

For better performance you can add the index:

```
create index ix1 on t (user_id, diff);
```

**Edit for updating column**

I misread your question. If you want to update an existing column you can do:

```
update t 
set is_registration_session = diff = (
  select max(diff) from t x where x.user_id = t.user_id and x.diff < 0
)
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. Can you clearify, I am not good in SQL, does this help me update column is_reg_session? I need exctacly to update values in this table and this column, not get new table.

Comment: Currently waiting a query to complete. But will it set True/False for is_reg_session? If yes then how?

Comment: @ArtemChirkov The result of the expression `diff = ( ... )` is a boolean. It will evaluate to `true` only for the row where `diff` is the biggest negative value, per subquery conditions.

Comment: thank you. Still waiting. 
Suspiciously long. I have 4.5 millions rows. Is this query fine for such number of rows?

Comment: query still running. seems not very good in my situation